# Lighting Question- How do I achieve pictures such as these?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, dslr, lighting, portrait, studio

I have a Nikon d5500 and a 55-200mm lens. I'm hoping to get pictures like these for a project- my main hang up is lighting? What sort of equipment should I use and are there any specific angles? Thanks!
[image]

Comment: That's a neat photo, but could you please credit the photographer [link is OK] & make sure [s]he allows re-distribution?

Comment: To help get the best answers (and to help others in the future!) please read [Important information for asking "What's this effect?"
questions](http://meta.photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3881/) and
edit this post accordingly. Make sure to use a descriptive title, 
too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You want a single broad diffuse source, to the left of the axis, whose centre is level with the centre of the lens and a dark light-absorbing background such as black velvet out of the way of any spill from the light source.

Place your camera (dead-level, use the aquarium water surface as a guide) an inch or two below the level of the surface.

Use a flag to block any light that might hit the background.

Use a big pretty-coloured subject.

Wait patiently.

Comment: For any domestic aquarium, the **#1** instruction ... move entire aquarium well away from wall & remove any nice backdrop it has. That's going to stop most people right in their tracks; aquaria not being known for their portability ;)

Comment: @Tetsujin That's an Icxycanthus which is over a foot long. The tank is huge which I didn't even want to address. The surface of the glass (if it's glass) is spotless. That's an issue. Too, is the rear of the tank which has been gobo-ed out. This set-up would take a minute or two in a sizeable environmentally controlled location. Yup!

Comment: I do get the feeling the photo was taken from **in** the tank, not through the glass - but that's a pure guess, based on nothing better than having had an aquarium [much smaller] of my own.